# Possible to pass an argument (i.e. BOOL) with NSSelectorFromString?

Tags: objective-c, arguments, selector

Instead of having code such as this:

```
switch(levelNumber) {
   case 1: [Settings unlockLvl1:YES]; break;
   case 2: [Settings unlockLvl2:YES]; break;
   case 3: [Settings unlockLvl3:YES]; break;
   case 4: [Settings unlockLvl4:YES]; break;
...
}
```

I was hoping to use NSSelectorFromString like this:

```
NSString *selectorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"unlockLvl%i", levelNumber];
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
[Settings performSelector:s];
```

However I am not sure that there is anywhere that I can correctly insert the (BOOL)YES argument when calling to the selector in this way? I would also want to be able to pass an int argument to a method called using a selector if possible.

Adding it to the selector string results in an "unrecognized selector" exception and crash.

[Settings performSelector:s withObject:???]; could work? But doesn't accept BOOL or int, required "id"

I'm trying to write my code so that there aren't multiple blocks of code for each level with the exact same function but just a number changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
If it's not possible... maybe there is another better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `performSelector:withObject:` but you need to wrap the `BOOL` in an `NSNumber`. Then you method need to unwrap the `NSNumber`.

```
BOOL someBool = YES; // or NO
[Settings performSelector:s withObject:@(someBOOL)];
```

Each of your `unlockLvlX` methods need to take an `NSNumber` parameter:

```
- (void)unlockLvl1:(NSNumber *)theBool {
    BOOL boolVal = [theBool boolValue];
    // do stuff with boolVal as needed
}
```

Comment: Yes!  This worked, thank you so much. For the int values I converted using [NSNumber numberWithInt: and then retrieved with intValue] 

Comment: For the `int` values you can still create the `NSNumber` using `@(someIntValue)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of doing that.

This part is common for both of them:

```
NSString *selectorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"unlockLvl%i:", levelNumber];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
```

1) Using `NSInvocation`:

```
BOOL boolArg = YES;

NSMethodSignature* signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:B"];
// or:
// NSMethodSignature* signature = [Settings.class methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.target = Settings.class; // or class instance
invocation.selector = selector;
[invocation setArgument:&boolArg atIndex:2];
[invocation invoke];
```

2) Using raw method:

```
typedef void (*MethodWithBoolArg)(id, SEL, BOOL);

MethodWithBoolArg method = (MethodWithBoolArg)[Settings.class methodForSelector:selector];
if (method != NULL)
    method(self, selector, YES);
```

Comment: For the second one, you can just use `obj_msgSend` directly: `MethodWithBoolArg f = (MethodWithBoolArg)obj_msgSend; f(self, selector, YES);` That's basically what the compiler does.